# Node JS parsing new Date("12345") to "+012345-01-01T06:00:00.000Z" (year 12345)

Tags: node.js, date

When I test this code in the browser, it processes dates in a logical way (`invalid date`), but in NodeJS `new Date("12345")` creates `+012345-01-01T06:00:00.000Z`

Here is my test for NodeJS

```
$ node -e 'console.log(new Date("12345"))'
// outputs: +012355-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
```

Here you can run it in browser

```js
console.log(new Date("12345"))
// outputs: null
```

Any idea why this is happening?  And how can I avoid this?

Comment: for the avoid part, you might want to check out moment.js. And you should add your browser and it's version, for me on linux with chrome 75 the snippet you provided outputs "+012344-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the JavaScript engine. In Firefox, dates after January 1, 10000 (year ten thousand) are apparently considered invalid:

```
> new Date("9999")
Date 9999-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

> new Date("10000")
Invalid Date
```

In Chrome (that uses V8, just like Node.js) it works perfectly:

```
> new Date("10000")
Sat Jan 01 10000 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
> new Date("12345")
Mon Jan 01 12345 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

So, to answer your question: different JavaScript engines have different limits related to which date is valid and which is not, but in general, having just a sequence of digits in a string makes it think it's January 1st of this year (corrected for a timezone used):

```
> new Date("2019")
Mon Dec 31 2018 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

Also note this. Chrome / Node.js:

```
> new Date("31")
Invalid Date
> new Date("32")
Thu Jan 01 2032 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

Firefox:

```
> new Date("1000")
Date 1000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

> new Date("999")
Invalid Date
```

Apparently, Firefox wants the year to have 4 digits exactly, while Chrome/V8 is more flexible.

Also, seems like Chrome/V8 has different logic parsing dates from `"1"` to `"12"` (using them as months) but this is totally different story.

Comment: Ah.  Well this seems silly all around.  If anything, I'd think that `(new Date("12345")).getTime() === (new Date(12345)).getTime()` would be the standard.  Especially given that dates are generally a database thing, where there's tons of potential for number to string conversions.

Comment: So would you recommend handling date formatting on the server side and not front-end?

Comment: @WilfredMulenga Probably. Or maybe use a third party library like moment.js mentioned in the comment above. Also, normal dates work just fine, it's just this very special use case that differs.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to how to avoid this issue, you can sort of standardize your value to date conversion like so:

```js
// all of these will produce the same date
const stringDate = "1970-01-01T00:00:12.345Z";
const numberString = "  12345  ";
const number = 12345;

function toDate(value) {
  if (typeof value === "string" && /^\d+$/.test(value.trim())) {
    value = parseInt(value);
  }
  return new Date(value)
}

console.log("string date", toDate(stringDate));
console.log("number string", toDate(numberString));
console.log("number", toDate(number));
```